# Intelligent split of string into an array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, preg-split

This code will split the string into an array that contains test and string:

```
$str = 'test string';
$arr = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);
```

But I also want to detect quotes and ignore the text between them when splitting, for example:

```
$str = 'test "Two words"';
```

This should also return an array with two elements, `test` and `Two words`.

And another form, if possible:

```
$str = 'test=Two Words';
```

So if the equal sign is present before any spaces, the string should be split by `=`, otherwise the other rules from above should apply.

So how can I do this with preg_split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php):

```
print_r(str_getcsv('test string'," "));
print_r(str_getcsv('test "Two words"'," "));
print_r(str_getcsv('test=Two Words',"="));
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => string
)
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => Two words
)
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => Two Words
)
```

You can use something like `preg_match` to check if there's an equal sign exist before space and then determine what delimiter to use.

Works only in PHP>=5.3 though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this could be done with regex, but how about just splitting the string by quotation marks, then by spaces, using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Given the string `'I am a string "with an embedded" string'`, you could first split by quotation marks, giving you `['I am a string', 'with an embedded', 'string']`, then you go over every other element in the array and split by spaces, resulting in `['I', 'am', 'a', 'string', 'with an embedded', 'string']`.

The exact code to do this you can probably write yourself. If not, let me know and I'll help you.

In your last example, just split by the equals symbol:

```
$str = 'test=Two Words';
print explode('=', $str);
```